# Trying to send a GET request to constant contact api in meteor js

Tags: javascript, http, meteor, get, constantcontact

I am trying to send a GET request to the [Constant Contact API](https://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/developer-guides/api-documentation-index.html) using the http package in [Meteor](https://docs.meteor.com/). I have generated a API key and a access token. There is a section in the docs about OAuth 2.0, however it mentions I don't need to use it if I am only using one Constant Contact account, which I am.

They have a API testing section and I have tried to take the same url and params in my HTTP GET  request in Meteor but it returns

```
statusCode: 401,
I20170927-06:36:08.874(-7)?      content: '[{"error_key":"http.status.unauthorized","error_message":"No authentication is present."}]'
```

Let me know of any other info I can provide, at this point I am pretty stuck.

Thanks

Here is my code

**Server**

```
HTTP.call( 'GET', 'https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/account/info?api_key=random-api-key', {}, function( error, response ) {
    if ( error ) {
      console.log( error );
    } else {
      console.log( response );
    }
  });
```

Comment: Presumably you have a real key in your call?

Comment: Yes I have a real key in my call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass both `API Key` and `Access Token`:

```
HTTP.get('https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/account/info?api_key=<API_KEY>', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>'
  }
}, function (err, response) {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and I still get a `statusCode: 401,
I20170927-07:53:59.678(-7)?      content: '[{"error_key":"http.status.unauthorized","error_message":"No authentication is present."}`

Comment: @AndersKitson You did replace `<API_KEY>` and `<ACCESS_TOKEN>` with actual key and token, right?

Comment: Yes I did replace them with the actual API_KEY and ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: @AndersKitson Could you test your key/token in their [API Tester](https://constantcontact.mashery.com/io-docs)? Do they work there?

Comment: I got it to work, I didn't realize `Bearer` was necessary in the header. All working now thanks.

Comment: @AndersKitson Glad it helped :)